# Get value of sequential variables in one string only through bash

Tags: string, bash

I have the following string:

```
testString="variable1=example1 variable2=example2"
```

I need a way through bash to extrapolate **example1** into a variable called **variable1**.

Note: I know beforehand the variable names that are going to be in that string, hence `variable1` and `variable2` and I need to enforce the search for those names.

I am the one actually constructing the `testString` and I used 1 space

Comment: Would the _dangerous_ (!) `eval` help you here? Or can you write a temporary file and then `source` it?

Comment: Why a string versus, say, an associative array? (e.g. `declare -A testvals=(["variable1"]="example1" ["variable2"]="example2")`. Or even just assigning the variables instead of extrapolating values. A small example of what you're trying to do and your attempted solution would help us understand better.

Comment: See [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @tjm3772 I thank you for sure for pointing out a better behavior but a string is what I need in the context I am working on.. but that's not relevant for this question. In short: working on Github reusable workflows, where calling one workflow from another needs several inputs. In my case I will pass a string that will contain all the parameters the called workflows needs. It's not relevant for this question though and that's I just mentioned the constraint of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `eval` -

```
$: testString="variable1=example1 variable2=example2"
$: declare $testString # unquoted!
$: echo $variable1
example1
```

But I'm hoping this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Would it not be better to (as tjm3772 suggests in the comments)

```
$: declare -A testvals=(["variable1"]="example1" ["variable2"]="example2")
$: echo "${testvals[variable1]}"
example1
```

or perhaps even

```
$: variable=( "" example1 example ) # empty cell zero
$: echo "${variable[1]}"
example1
```

?

Comment: first solution worked exactly how I needed it. It's simple and clean and allowed me not using regex, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the variable names in advance, this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates a safe way of doing what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

testString="variable1=example1 variable2=example2"

read -r -a vars <<<"$testString"
for v in "${vars[@]}"; do
    case $v in
        variable1=*) variable1=${v#*=};;
        variable2=*) variable2=${v#*=};;
    esac
done

printf 'variable1=%s\n' "$variable1"
printf 'variable2=%s\n' "$variable2"
```

- The code assumes that there are no space or tab characters in any of the variable values.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${v#*=}`.

Comment: this solution also worked and hopefully will be useful for others! In my case there is no risk of injecting weird values that might be dangerous. That's why I chose the other solution cause dryer and effective. Thanks in any case!